# Displaying Legend for Variable Width Line in QGIS

Tags: qgis, legend

I am using QGIS v3.4 to display a simple line as a line of varying width using the variable line width attribute facility of QGIS (please see screenshot below).

[image]

The layer displays correctly within the map window however I am experiencing challenges in displaying the variable lines as a legend within the print layout window.

Comment: QGIS has known issues with displaying variable-sized symbols in a legend. Check the issue tracker (issues.qgis.org) to see if this particular issue has been reported yet, and whether anyone is working on fixing it. In the meantime, just crop the legend part out of the screenshot you posted, and add it to the print composer as an image.